# What is the utility of the design pattern Observer when you can get the same results without using it?

Tags: php, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm aware of the use of the pattern observer but for the moment I'm seeing that it's a useless layer to do operations on observer objets while you can do the same operation without the need to use this design pattern !

Can somebody correct me if I'm wrong and explain to be using a concret example the utility and the importance of this design pattern ?

I can see that it offers more code organisation but when should I use it ?

For example here's an implementation of the Observer pattern in PHP :

Here's the observed or the subject class

```
  // Dès que cet attribut changera on notifiera les classes observatrices.
protected $name;

public function attach(SplObserver $observer)
{$this->observers[] = $observer;
  }

  public function detach(SplObserver $observer)
  {
    if (is_int($key = array_search($observer, $this->observers, true)))
   {
  unset($this->observers[$key]);
    }
  }

  public function notify()
  {
     foreach ($this->observers as $observer)
    {
         $observer->update($this);
    }
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
}

  public function setNom($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->notify();
  }
}
```

Here are the observers containing the actions made when they're notified :

```
<?php
class Observer1 implements SplObserver
{
  public function update(SplSubject $obj)
  {
    echo 'Observer1 has been notified! Nouvelle valeur de l\'attribut <strong>nom</strong> : ', $obj->getName();
  }
}

 class Observer2 implements SplObserver
{
  public function update(SplSubject $obj)
  {
    echo 'Observer2 a has been notified! Nouvelle valeur de l\'attribut <strong>nom</strong> : ', $obj->getName();
  }
}
```

And here's how we use them

```
$o = new Observee;

$o->attach(new Observer1); // Adding an observer.

$o->attach(new Observer2); // Adding another observer.

$o->setNom('Victor'); // We mmofidy this attribute and the observers have taken the speficified action
```

Now as you can see I don't need to implement the two functions notify() and update() to make the observers take some action.

I don't see which problem does this Design Pattern responds to .

Comment: *"I can see that it offers more code organisation"* – well… that's not enough of a reason?

Answer (score 0):

The Observer pattern's **Intent** is as follows:

> Define a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

It's not so explicit that the problem is one of maintainability, but part of the reason for Observer is to decouple subjects from its observers. This is important in layered systems where you don't want stable classes depending on unstable classes (dependency in the wrong direction).

The classic use for Observer is model-view separation. The View (GUI) tends to be unstable. That is, it require lots of changes to the code over time, because:

- the human users are never happy with the design,
- there are newer technologies that improve the "view" such as video recognition, voice recognition (Siri, OK Google, etc.), haptics, 3D goggles, etc.
- there's a need for implementations of a "view" on different platforms, mobile, etc.

The Model code in these systems doesn't want to know (be coupled to) all these details, since you'll likely have to change the Model code, too, when your users ask you to change the View. That makes your system harder to maintain.

[image]

So, Observer works by providing to the Model a very stable interface, called `Observer` which won't change, even though the software that implements it (the views) can change a lot. I like to think of the Observer interface as a friendly-looking (stable) mask behind which all the crazy ever-changing views hide behind. It keeps the Model classes happy by insulating them from the changes.

[image]

Yes, it's an additional layer, but it's a *stable* layer to the model that still allows updates to be communicated to views (Observers) despite their changing.

**TL;DR** The `Observer` interface protects the `Subject` classes from any changes in the classes implementing `Observer`. This makes your code easier to maintain.

The best way to appreciate Observer is *not* to use it. You can live with fixing your models (Subjects in the Observer pattern) each time the views (Observers) change. If you feel the pain of those changes each time, you may appreciate the pattern. This is IMO one of the biggest challenges to learning the GoF patterns (the *maintenance suffering* required to truly appreciate their benefit).

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and time :) ! But can you offer some code snippets with this theory since I'm only a technician in developement and not an engineer...English is not my mother tongue and I need to actully experiment the implementation .

Comment: @HamzaELjaouhari Can you edit your question with the concrete example that made you have this question in the first place? Was it in PHP?

Comment: @HamzaELjaouhari Your code examples are too abstract. `Observer1` would be some *real* class. The `echo` is trivial; `update` would display `nom` in a particular `<div>` class of the page (or something). Users will likely ask you to modify that over time. With Observer, the details about the `<div>` are encapsulated in the `update` method. *Without* Observer, however, Subject can know directly the details of how to communicate the change to `Observer1` (or it could even modify the `<div>` directly). However, presentation details would be in subject classes; changing them would be difficult.